# Assign local storage to react state. React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, authentication, local-storage, token, react-hooks

I'm trying to sign a user in, and update my global context with the user data. To keep the user signed in I'm storing their data in local storage.

I'm using react-hooks to take care of the state, hence I have defined a state: `let [userData, setUserData] = useState({});`.

Since I wan't to keep the user signed in I store their data in local storage during sign in. This works and the data does in fact get stored in local storage.

My problem is however that I can't set the initial `userData` state equal to the current data from local storage. In other words the `userData` state gets reset to default on reload.

I thought that getting the initial data from local storage and assigning it to state inside the `useEffect` hook would work. But the state does not update when calling `setUserData` inside `useEffect`.

AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = props => {
    let [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

    const loginUser = (data) => {
        localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({
            key: data.key,
            id: data.id,
            email: data.email,
            first_name: data.first_name,
            last_name: data.last_name
        })); // Save the user object in local storage
        setUserData({
            key: data.key,
            id: data.id,
            email: data.email,
            first_name: data.first_name,
            last_name: data.last_name
        }); // Set user data    
    };

    const logoutUser = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('userData');
        setUserData({}); // Empty user data state
        newToast('Successfully signed out');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const localUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
        if (localUser && localUser.key) {
            setUserData({
                key: localUser.key,
                id: localUser.id,
                email: localUser.email,
                first_name: localUser.first_name,
                last_name: localUser.last_name
            }); // Set user data    
        }
    }, [])


    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userData, loginUser, logoutUser, newToast }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Signin.js:

```
const Signin = props => {
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    let [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);
    const { userData, loginUser, newToast } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors, setError, clearError } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = e => {
        setLoading(true);
        setFormError(false);
        clearError(); // Clear all erros on form        
        axios
            .post('users/auth/login/', {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                email: `${e.email}`,
                password: `${e.password}`,
            })
            .then(res => {
                const { data } = res
                loginUser(data);
                newToast('Successfully signed in');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const { data } = error.response;
                console.log(data);
                data.email && setError("email", "", data.email);
                data.password1 && setError("password", "", data.password1);
                setFormError(true);
            })

        setLoading(false);
    };
    return ( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Updated answer (Aug. 15, 2022):**

Since accessing the local storage on every render is expensive, it is preferred to only access it during the initial render (see Wayne Ellery's comment).

So quoting Erol's solution:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([], () => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem('userData');
    return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
});
```

**Original answer:**

So I figured out a solution!

In AuthContext.js i didn't need to assign the state in `useEffect`.
Instead I get the initial data directly when defining the state hooks:

```
const localUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')) || {};
let [userData, setUserData] = useState(localUser);
```

That way I don't need the `useEffect` hook at all.

I hope this is the recommended way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you could do the following:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([], () => {
        const localData = localStorage.getItem('userData');
        return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

How about to use useReducer like this?

```
const [user, setUser] = useReducer((prev, cur) => {
  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(cur));
  return cur;
}, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')));
```

You can call

```
setUser({ key: '1', ... });
```